# restrict CUBIST condition parameters

Tags: c, r, rules

There is CUBIST algorithm to generate rule-based models.

it's available as C source:
https://www.rulequest.com/cubist-win.html

and R package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cubist/index.html

it generates rules that look like this:

```
if
    class in {CAR, VAN}
    displ <= 4.6
    fuel in {R, D, C}
then
    fuel cost = -49.2 + 163 cylinders + 1306 displ/cyl + 77 displ
                + 46 valves/cyl
```

**Now what I need is to specify which of the input parameters can be used in condition and which can be used in a formula.** Original code doesn't allow that and splits parameters by itself.

I've looked at C code and it's quite complex.

Is there any simpler way to solve my issue (besides modifying C code)? I've tried to find any such modifications in the net, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the parameters can be tuned.
Here is an example from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cubist/vignettes/cubist.pdf

```
    library(caret)
    set.seed(1)
    cTune <- train(x = trainingPredictors, y = trainingOutcome,
                   "cubist",
                    tuneGrid = expand.grid(.committees = c(1, 10, 50, 100),
                                           .neighbors = c(0, 1, 5, 9)),
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
     cTune
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting used to it!

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this helps to specify which fields can be used for conditions and which are for formula.